# Why i can not create media player in the android alarm manager onReceive method?

Tags: android

I want want application to start every 10 second play a sound alarm,i'm use the android alarm manager,every thing is good,but in the this line:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
```

i want create media player,up line get error this parameter i show error this picture:
[image]

How can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: thanks my friend it's work,please post your solution to i vote up you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this` with `context`. Although, creating `MediaPlayer` in a broadcast receiver is not a good way. Because `onReceive` should return ASAP.